# Showing certain id's from table join mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have created a table join with `users` table and `teams` table.
The users can only belong to one team so they have a team_id to their account.

How can I show all of the different groups with the members that are part of that group?

This is the code that I have. Currently it only displays the team with the id of 1, there is 1 user in the user table with the team_id of 1

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
 $user->redirect('index.php');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM teams
INNER JOIN users
ON teams.id=users.team_id
HAVING teams.id=1");
$stmt->execute();
$teamRow=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<h1>Teams</h1> 
<table>
 <tr> 
     <?php foreach($teamRow as $row): ?>   
        <th><?=$row['team_name']?></th>
        </tr> 
         </tr> 
<td> <?=$row['user_name']?></td>
 </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<a href="home.php">Home</a>
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain more "How could I show all of the different groups with the members that are part of that group?" pls ?

Comment: if i understand correctly ... you can create user join team group by team where team NOT xxx_team ?

Comment: For example I have a team with the id of 1, I then want to show the team name, then underneath that show all users with that team id, so I could have a user called Phil, and then in another column, team_id 1. Phil would then be shown under the team that has team_id 1.

I am able to do this with the code I have at the moment, but I want to be able to do it with more than 1 team, so team_id 2 has 5 users to it, and then display the 5 users

Comment: you expect result like a ... team1 = [user1, user2], team2 = [user1] etc..?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it, I should have worded it like that to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

1) remove `HAVING clause` from query and let just `simple JOIN` on users and add `ORDER BY team_name ASC`.
2) do logic in php loop

```
<table>
    <?php $teamName = ''; // assign teamName for loop ?>
    <?php foreach($teamRow as $row): ?>
    <?php
        if($row['team_name'] != $teamName) {
            $teamName = $row['team_name']; // set teamName for loop if not equal
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?=$row['team_name']?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['user_name']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="home.php">Home</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The logic is: (use case)
- in loop, if $row team_name is not equal teamName so display teamName and set
- then show user_name
- loop again, $row team_name is equal to teamName so dont display teamName again

hope it helps

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Iam glad to help you. If it is answer for your problem please mark.